# ASP.NET performance: find what consumes execution time

Tags: asp.net, performance

Recently we changed a dedicated server from Windows Server 2003 to a more powerful server, based on Window Server 2012. A problem appeared on the new server, that sometimes requests are running too slow.

I did an additional logging at various stages of requests, and get confusing data. For example, a call to web service method takes 7 seconds between PreRequestHandlerExecute and PostRequestHandlerExecute (tracked time in Global.asax), but at the same time there are log records made inside the called method, that show execution time of this method was less than a second (log records and the start and end of the method have same milliseconds). So it means that the method itself executed fast. The question is what consumed 7 seconds between PreRequestHandlerExecute and PostRequestHandlerExecute?

Note that the problem is not replicatable, I can never replicate it myself, but only see this in log happending to other people (I programmed an email notification sent to me when it happens that request takes more than 3 seconds).

Sometimes the execution time on some pages goes to such crazy values as 2 minutes, and from log records I have on different stages of the page execusion I cannot see what consumes that time. The problem did not exist on the old 2003 server.

Comment: Assuming you're looking at webforms applications, have you investigated IIS's built-in tracing?

Comment: What are you using for logging? Is it maybe just that the log buffer is filling and it only writes to disk (with a timestamp) when it fills up (which could be after the request is served?)

Comment: Adrian, I have only used my own log records for analyzing this. I will definitely check the IIS's built-in tracing. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Mark, I use log4net for logging. I don't think the problem is log buffering, because in other cases log records have different timestaps for requests that really take time to execute due to the logic they do.

Comment: Point to note, unless you specifically @-mention a person they don't get notified of your response (and don't know there are comments to respond to).

Comment: @Adrian, I investigated it via IIS built-in tracing, and it appears that the time is taken between GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START and GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_END. Though I don't know why it happens. In most cases it takes zero time, but sometimes it is up to 20 seconds. Example:

Comment: 178. GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START  11:05:48.190 
179. GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_END BytesReceived="17", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully. (0x0)" 11:06:09.815